# Value of JLabel is not being updated using setText() in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I know many people have asked this question before but I couldn't find any answer that solved my problem. My code is like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    TEXT.setText("ON");
    myfunction(); //runs for a very long time
}
```

The original text of `JLabel` is `"OFF"`. Now I want to change the text to `"ON"` when the mouse is clicked but the text doesn't set until `myfunction()` is complete (which may take several minutes).

I have tried the invalidate function, making a separate function for setting the text but nothing is working.

Please help me with this problem!

Comment: You must run myfunction() in a separate thread if possible. What does myfunction() do?

Comment: It gets data through ethernet and adds it to the database. I want to avoid threads...

Comment: there is no way around threads. writing good code with swing always involves the use of threads in some form or another. read my answer where i explain it in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `mouseClicked(...)` is executed on the [UI Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). That is the [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) that is responsible for handling all sorts of user actions (like a mouse click) and also the drawing of components (like updating the text of the label on screen). If you execute your long running method call on the UI thread, it will be blocked and can't draw anything until execution is complete. You'll have to use [multi threading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) to get around this problem.

The following might not be the most elegant solution, but if you are new to multi threading it will get the job done:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    TEXT.setText("ON");
    (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            myfunction();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

It will spawn a new `Thread` that handles your method, which will let the UI `Thread` continue doing its thing. consider deactivating the button that has just been clicked, so the user can't start the execution while it is already in progress (which usually is what you want..)